# LTE signal strength vs GSM signal strength in Android

Tags: android, signal-strength, lte

I want to show the network signal strength in my app.I am using LTE network for transmitting data and want to show any real time variations in network strength.I was able to get the GSM signal strength. I want to know that the GSM signal strength also reflects the signal strength of LTE.

Comment: no gsm signal strength and LTE signal strengths are separate

Comment: @Bhargav How can i get LTE signal strength in Android.

Comment: CellSignalStrengthLte class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html

Answer (score 0):

no gsm signal strength and LTE signal strengths are separate,
"How can i get LTE signal strength in Android"

CellSignalStrengthLte class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html